# django.contrib.auth views and template vars

Tags: django, django-authentication

In my "root" template I have something like this

```
{% if special %}
some_special_html
{% endif %}
```

The `special` template var is inserted in template by certain views.

The problem is that I need the `password_change` view to allso set the `special` template var.

What's best way to approach this?

Currently, the `password_change` view is called directly from urls.py:

```
url(r'^change_password/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.password_change',
    {'template_name': 'profile/password_change.html'},
    name='password_change'),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of at least Django 1.3, the `password_change` view does take extra context, although the documentation doesn't mention it.

You can pass extra keyword arguments to a view by using the `kwargs` argument of the `url` function, so to get the extra context in, do something like this:

```
url(r'^password/change/$',
    auth_views.password_change,
    {'template_name': 'profile/password_change.html'},
    name='password_change',
    kwargs=dict(extra_context={'special': 'special'}),
    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Either move your processing of the `special` var into a context_processor, or just wrap the `password_change` auth view with your own view that passes in the correct context.

Comment: ok, I have wrapped the view, but don't know how to "pass the correct context in"

Comment: `password_change` doesn't take any extra context. It does instantiate a `RequestContext` though.

Comment: @Ignacio: You're right.  @Cek: I'd just copy the entirety of the view code and make the changes you need.

Comment: @sdolan It seems like a very non-django-pythonic way of solving the problem :) 
But hey! if it works...

Comment: @ignacio My django-foo fell flat on the floor.

Comment: @Cek: The django way would be to put the logic into a context processor, but yes, just copying works just fine :)  I would add some unit tests around it to make sure that if anything changes in core that affects it you'll know about it.